# HTML - fieldset - stretching the background image

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon.

I am still pretty new to website development so I apologize if what I am asking is considered simple but I couldn't find a workable answer to my question.

**Goal**

All I am trying to accomplish is to have a fieldset with a background image that is stretched, therefore if I change the size of the fieldset, the image should change accordingly as well.

**What I currently have**

```
<form action="" style="width: 400px;height: 200px;display:inline-block;">
<fieldset style="background:url(/MusicPlayerBackground.png) no-repeat;width:1000px;height: 2000px;">
<legend align="center">Playlist:</legend>


</fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there something that should go in the style part for the fieldset?

I have tried this below, as suggested on another forum:

```
background: url(background: url(/MusicPlayerBackground.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover;
```

However this results in a blank fieldset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cover, you need to use `100% 100%`.

```
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7US/1/)

Also, make sure that if you're going to change the image by putting an inline style that you are using `background-image:`, otherwise you're going to overwrite all the background properties set up in your css file.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%; ftw! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the second `background:url`, the background will show.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgB59/1/)

Answer (score 0):

your width and height must have a value of 100% rather than 1000px